# Ubuntu Focal Server with Desktop

Tags: server, 20.04, unity, icons

I used a **Focal Server Image** and then installed:

```
apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends ubuntu-unity-desktop ttf-ubuntu-font-family gnome-shell-extensions
```

but the desktop still looks different to the original desktop from the desktop version.
I then tried several packages like `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons` but without success.

Does someone know what exactly needs to be done to get the same icons and possibly settings?

Left Server Version, Right Desktop Installer Version:

[image: Desktop from Server Installer]   [image: Desktop from Desktop Installer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the Yaru theme. You may be able to get the look somewhat close to the stock desktop with:

```
sudo apt install yaru-theme-unity yaru-theme-gtk yaru-theme-icon yaru-theme-sound
```

There are a number of Yaru theme packages available, and you can find them in apt like this:

```
sudo apt search yaru
```

This will give you something like:

```
yaru-theme-gnome-shell/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 20.04.11.1 all [installed,automatic]
  Yaru GNOME Shell desktop theme from the Ubuntu Community

yaru-theme-gtk/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 20.04.11.1 all [installed,automatic]
  Yaru GTK theme from the Ubuntu Community

yaru-theme-icon/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 20.04.11.1 all [installed,automatic]
  Yaru icon theme from the Ubuntu Community

yaru-theme-sound/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 20.04.11.1 all [installed,automatic]
  Yaru sound theme from the Ubuntu Community

yaru-theme-unity/focal-updates,focal-updates 20.04.11.1 all
  Yaru Unity theme from the Ubuntu Community
```

<sub>**Note:** The above output comes from a 20.04 LTS Desktop installation. As you've installed the Unity theme, the first `apt` command in this answer replaces `yaru-theme-gnome-shell` with `yaru-theme-unity`.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much! First I installed the wrong package - it should be the ubuntu-gnome-desktop, then the yaru-theme-icon package did the trick.